# Changing the style in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have the following list,

```
l={{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}
```

I was wondering how can I convert it into:

```
   output: {"ab", "cd"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
StringJoin /@ l
```

This is Map[StringJoin, l]

Comment: or `StringJoin @@@ l`.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do so just now by using:

```
Table[StringJoin[l[[i]]], {i, Length[l]}]
```